# Updating current line in VB Console

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, console, control-characters

I am trying to write out to console a percentage of data loading. I tried to use C# syntax which would be `Console.Write("\rPercentage: " + nCurrent + "/" + nTotal;` however in VB I get the actual character 'r' being displayed in my string. Is there a special code I need to insert in order to update my cursor to the beginning of the line so that I may reuse that line?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use vbCr to generate a carriage return character:

```
        Console.Write("{0}Percentage: {1}/{2}", vbCr, nCurrent, nTotal)
```